# User Idle Detection

Tags: c++, winapi

i want to detect User Idle Detection in c++
i used this winapi:

```
LASTINPUTINFO last_input;
last_input.cbSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
last_input.dwTime = 0;
GetLastInputInfo(&last_input)
```

this methods work correctly with user Input like (mouse and keyboard),
but when i watch a movie  this methods return wrong tickcount
i want right like "windows screen Saver" that detect user activity like (watch movie,mouse and keyboard) perfectly
how i can do this
thx

Comment: It's not the screensaver that detects that a movie is being watched. It's the video player, that communicates to the screensaver, that it shall be inhibited by *not* passing the WM_SYSCOMMAND / SC_SCREENSAVER message to DefWindowProc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/screen-saver-library?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @datenwolf The video player should preferably be using [`SetThreadExecutionState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) instead to tell Windows that the screen display is needed, so Windows doesn't try to invoke the screensaver at all. See [System Sleep Criteria](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-sleep-criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect user idle, actually no user input, no display required, you can determines whether a screen saver is currently running using [`SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

If you want to get time period of user idle, you can see the [last user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) time as starting point and the time screen saver starts running as end point. Time difference between them is what you want.

More references: "[System Sleep Criteria](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-sleep-criteria)", "[SystemParametersInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa?redirectedfrom=MSDN)".